# Python 3.6 IPython console can't find ipykernel or cloudpickle after adding new conda environment for Python 2.7

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, spyder

I'm working on a project where I need to switch between Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 occasionally. So I recently set up a Python 2.7 environment in Anaconda using the following command.

`conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda`

By default, Anaconda uses a Python 3.6 environment and Spyder (and the IPython console) had been working perfectly prior to the creation of the Python 2.7 environment. However, after creating the new environment, I can no longer use the IPython console in Spyder when I launch in the Python 3.6 environment (works fine for my new Python 2.7 environment) because for some reason it doesn't recognize the ipykernel and cloudpickle modules (even though I've checked and re-installed these modules for my Python 3.6 environment). Below is the error continue to get.

> An error ocurred while starting the kernel Your Python environment or
>   installation doesn't have the ipykernel and cloudpickle modules
>   installed on it. Without these modules is not possible for Spyder to
>   create a console for you.
>
> You can install them by running in a system terminal:
>
> pip install ipykernel cloudpickle
>
> or
>
> conda install ipykernel cloudpickle

If anyone has any ideas how I can fix this, let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The creation of kernels in external interpreters is semi-broken in our current version (Spyder **3.2.8**). By this I mean that the process is very brittle (i.e. sometimes work and others don't, depending on your particular configuration).

We'll fix this in Spyder **3.3**, to be released in June/2018.